# Close a Window with onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover, onmouseout

I'm trying to do a simple page that when you put your mouse over an  a popUp appears, and when you put your mouse out of the window,  it closes.
My code is quite simple, but doesn't work.

```
article class="news" onmouseover="openWindow();" >
  #some html code here
</article>
```

And the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openWindow(){
        mywin=window.open('','','width=200,height=100, left=650 top=300');
        mywin.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
        mywin.document.setAttribute('onmouseout="closeWindow();"')
    }
    function closeWindow(){
         mywin.close();
    }

</script>
```

So openWindow() works fine, but closeWindow don't.
Some idea of how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a right way to hide a window but I just edit your code as per your question.

```
function openWindow(){
        mywin=window.open('#','','width=200,height=100, left=650 top=300');
        mywin.document.write("<p onmouseout='window.close()'>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
}
function closeWindow(){
     mywin.close();
}
```

Instead a window open you should try any jquery plugin or other custom code.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I wanted. 
I cannot used Jquery, just javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a real window, could you get away with a JQuery dialog window.  This is the preferred method to create popups of pure HTML.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/