# How do I write OnMouseOut so it closes a popup tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this code creating a popup/tooltip when specific text is hovered by the user:

```
   function popup() {
   $('#example').load("example.html");
}
```

I add this to make the tooltip appear:

```
<div id="example" onmouseover="popup(this)" onmouseout="popup.close();">Hover over this!</div>
```

What that's doing, I'm happy I succeeded figuring out, is when the user hovers over the text "Hover over this!" a window appears and displays `example.html` as the content of the popup window. I included `onmouseout="popup.close();"` in an attempt to get it to automatically close.

I'm trying to get it to also close the popup when the user moves their mouse away from the text. I've tried this:

```
   function popup() {
   $('#example').load("example.html");
}

   function close(){
   popup(this).close();
}
```

Which, obviously to those who know more than me, didn't cause the window to close.

How do I have to write a very simple version of this code correctly so it closes the popup onMouseOut?

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17108199/19113703) solution that's very similar but I'm not 100% sure how to edit that either to get it loading the external page I want.

Edit: Nope. The solution in the above link didn't work out for me.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36002936/19113703) solution gets me close but the page on mdn DOES NOT list any of the options in the example code. Where did they hide the window options that let us disable the close, minimize, scrollbars, etc at? 

And more so WHY the <f*ck> did they hide that information?????? This is the exafct reason I can't stand MDN. It's a maze to navigate and find anything, they don't have examples we can edit, it's a horrible reference site in my opinion. I found the code that actually works on w3schools.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super skilled in JS, so bear with me. It looks like you have a function to display the popup, so I will assume that is working well. I only have a few suggestions, my best one is to have an if/else statement.
If the mouse cursor is over the text, display the popup.
Else, hide the popup.
I don't see a reason why the functions you set up wouldn't be working, so you should just be able to add that. For fear of giving incorrect advice, I will not be showing code because I suck at JS and it will probably be incorrect. But do some research and see if that works. Some other people might have better feedback than me.

Comment: I really don't know what the language is. I originally had it tagged as javascript and someone edited it to add JQuery saying that's what it was. So which is it? 
I have no clue how to properly write an if statement. 
Our skill levels are about the same, Nebula. If I were able to figure it out I wouldn't be asking this question. lol
I thought how I had it written would work too, but it doesn't. And that was as close to working as I got it after 3 days searching and trying it different ways. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to know the basics of JS.
jQuery is its library/framework, written by an enthusiastic programmers like you. At first, JavaScript.

```
      <div onmouseover="this.innerText='7'" 
       onmouseout="this.innerText='77'">Hover please!</div>
```

On mousing over it, the text is 7, on mouse  out it is 77 .
This is basic.

And the language is not Java.

JavaScript is easier a little bit.

This is what you got to know now.

Comment: My code doesn't change text. It opens a window. How to I close the window the code I included opens?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing here you have to know is HTML on the web.
Then you get to JavaScript (basically without jQuery at first ).

You were using the jQuery library ajax methods of JavaScript .

```
     <!--normal code (it's a comment!)-->    
       <script>function getLoad(){return '<iframe src="example.html"/>' }</script>

      (return means give out value). 
  <div onmouseover="this.innerHTML=getLoad()" onmouseout="this.innerHTML='Hover please!'">Hover please! 
  </div>
```